# Read chosen data from json file highcharts

Tags: json, highcharts

```
[
  ["_id","his_corpid","his_date","his_open","his_high","his_low","his_close","his_vol"  ],
  ["54b8ef5d0cf24b8f3b43e8b5","0119","2015-01-15T16:00:00.000Z","0.155"," 0.155","0.155 ","0.155","122,000"  ],
  ["54ae63520cf24b8f3b43e6c7","0119","2015-01-07T16:00:00.000Z","0.15"," 0.155","0.15 ","0.15","809,300"  ],
  ["549a398f2601cbdd859280ac","0119","2014-12-22T16:00:00.000Z","0.16"," 0.165","0.155 ","0.16","281,500"  ],
  ["549a398f2601cbdd859280ad","0119","2014-12-21T16:00:00.000Z","0.16"," 0.165","0.16 ","0.16","2,700"  ],
  ["549a398f2601cbdd859280ae","0119","2014-12-18T16:00:00.000Z","0.16"," 0.165","0.15 ","0.16","375,800"  ]]
```

I have spent hours going through this but could not figure it out. Would appreciate your help if you could give me hints in choosing the date as x-axis and y- as his-close(value) to create line chart. Thnx in advance

Comment: just to add, the first row shows the title and the rest of the raws are the values.

Comment: Can you please edit your Q and post your code/what you have tried? As you're new you should also check out http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Just loop over all arrays in the main array, starting from index=1. In that loop generate format required by Highcharts (in your case `[timestamp, value]` would be good). Just make sure you have timestamp and value as numbers, not string. Use `Date.parse` and `parseFloat` methods.